# Who has been denied membership in United Federation of Planets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

During the TNG series, several planets are shown in various stages of the application process for membership with the UFP but we don't see the final outcome of those applications, but it doesn't look good.

The Anticans applied for membership to the United Federation of Planets. The Enterprise-D transported their delegates to the planet Parliament to help resolve a long-standing dispute with their sister planet, Selay, as part of the admission process. (TNG: 1x07, "Lonely Among Us")

The Angosians applied but were apparently turned down.
Picard tells the Angosian government that they must make a decision regarding the fate of their veterans and that he has all the information he needs for his report, and, if they wish to reapply for Federation membership, their application will be given all due consideration...
(TNG: 3x11, "The Hunted")

Looks like the Angosians got shut down and the Anticans were a real longshot for acceptance. Have there been others who have been denied membership?

Comment: [Kesprytt](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Attached_(episode)) probably was denied.

Comment: Well **I** sent a letter to UFoP c/o San Francisco and never got a reply!

Comment: @Xantec -You're probably right, they do seem a bit too... skittish.

Comment: Similar question here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51988/has-the-federation-ever-kicked-a-planet-or-civilization-out-of-the-federation (but not a duplicate ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most obvious answers (within the TV canon) are;

## Kesprytt III:

As a result of their internal disputes Riker (in the TNG Episode "[Attached](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/260.txt)") strongly indicates that his recommendation will be to refuse admission;

> **RIKER :** *As First Officer of the Enterprise I think I can promise you that is not going to happen. The Kes will be denied membership.*

### Deneb IV

The Bandi homeworld was refused Federation entry after it became clear that their 'starbase building technology' required the subjugation of sentient creatures in "[Encounter at Farpoint, Part I+II](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/102.txt)"

### Beta Renner II + Angosia III

You've already mentioned Beta Renner II from the epsiode "Lonely Among us" and Angosia III from "The Hunted" as worlds that were told to get their acts together before reapplying.

---

---

Moving down the canon scale to the EU books, there are a number of references to worlds denied Federation membership;

**Parath'aa** is refused entry in the TOS book [The Disinherited](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Disinherited) due to the "brutality of their leaders"

The Planet [Halka](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Halka) (originally seen in TOS: "Mirror, Mirror") was granted entry into the Federation after multiple refusals. It's notable that they are referred to as being the main trading partner between the Federation and **Halka I, IV and IX which were refused Federation membership**. Halka itself is referenced in the TOS novel "[Preserver](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Preserver_%28novel%29)" as being 'aligned with the Federation', suggesting their membership was never fully confirmed.

Comment: Good answer @Richard. If you run across any more later, please feel free to add them.

Comment: @Morgan - There's bound to be a bunch more in the EU. I've got 1300 Trek books in my library so there's a fair chance that *anything you ask* will have happened at least once.

Comment: -I figured you might :-). I do have some trepidation about EU in general though. I don't have much problem with 'filling in some gaps' left by the series', but balk at when they create an evolving and whole new canonesque type universe. If I had more (any) experience with the quality/consistency of the EU I might soften that opinion.

Comment: There's a good chance that the [Antedeans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Antedean) had some problems getting accepted.

Comment: @muistooshort - Ah, I recall that the fish-men weren't the real delegates. They were assassins who'd somehow replaced the delegates...

Comment: Do we know if they were the real delegates or not though? Imposter-assassins could be overlooked and fixed through diplomacy but delegate-assassins would, presumably, be frowned upon.

Comment: @muistooshort - The quote seems pretty clear; *Mrs Troi :* ***They're not delegates. Those two are assassins.***